# How to replace encoded missing values as missing values in rapidminer?

Tags: machine-learning, missing-data, rapidminer, eda

I am currently working in covid data analysis using the dataset from [COVID-19 DATASET](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/meirnizri/covid19-dataset). I am using Rapidminer for this project.
In this dataset, the missing values are labeled as 97,98,99 in all other column and the death_year column has missing values as 9999-99-99.

I am trying to replace the missing values in the manually by chaining the replace operator but the system doesn't show all of the operator.
[image: Rapidminer system design]

I am tasked to do some eda and ml operation in this dataset. But for that removing or dealing with missing values are deemed necessary.

Comment: As a side note: replacing with an actual question mark character is something completely different than a missing value. Missing values are only displayed as ? in the RapidMiner result view, since just showing empty cells might be confusing. If you want to create "real" missing values, you can use the basic constants (like MISSING_NOMINAL...) in the function expression of Generate Attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Declare Missing Value` operator. This works for nominal and numeric attributes and you state what value should be missing throughout the example set.

Here's an example XML process (copy the XML below and paste into an empty RapidMiner XML pane)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="10.1.001">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="10.1.001" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <parameter key="logverbosity" value="init"/>
    <parameter key="random_seed" value="2001"/>
    <parameter key="send_mail" value="never"/>
    <parameter key="notification_email" value=""/>
    <parameter key="process_duration_for_mail" value="30"/>
    <parameter key="encoding" value="SYSTEM"/>
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="utility:create_exampleset" compatibility="10.1.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Create ExampleSet" width="90" x="112" y="34">
    <parameter key="generator_type" value="comma separated text"/>
    <parameter key="number_of_examples" value="100"/>
    <parameter key="use_stepsize" value="false"/>
    <list key="function_descriptions"/>
    <parameter key="add_id_attribute" value="false"/>
    <list key="numeric_series_configuration"/>
    <list key="date_series_configuration"/>
    <list key="date_series_configuration (interval)"/>
    <parameter key="date_format" value="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"/>
    <parameter key="time_zone" value="SYSTEM"/>
    <parameter key="input_csv_text" value="aa,bb,cc,dd&#10;99,3.1,23,2023-09-12&#10;98,97,1.1,2023-09-13&#10;3.1,2,1,9999-99-99"/>
    <parameter key="column_separator" value=","/>
    <parameter key="parse_all_as_nominal" value="false"/>
    <parameter key="decimal_point_character" value="."/>
    <parameter key="trim_attribute_names" value="true"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="declare_missing_value" compatibility="10.1.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Declare Missing Value (4)" width="90" x="246" y="136">
    <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="all"/>
    <parameter key="attribute" value="dd"/>
    <parameter key="attributes" value="|a4"/>
    <parameter key="use_except_expression" value="false"/>
    <parameter key="value_type" value="attribute_value"/>
    <parameter key="use_value_type_exception" value="false"/>
    <parameter key="except_value_type" value="time"/>
    <parameter key="block_type" value="attribute_block"/>
    <parameter key="use_block_type_exception" value="false"/>
    <parameter key="except_block_type" value="value_matrix_row_start"/>
    <parameter key="invert_selection" value="false"/>
    <parameter key="include_special_attributes" value="false"/>
    <parameter key="mode" value="nominal"/>
    <parameter key="numeric_value" value="99.0"/>
    <parameter key="nominal_value" value="9999-99-99"/>
    <parameter key="expression_value" value="a4==&quot;bbbb&quot;"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="declare_missing_value" compatibility="10.1.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Declare Missing Value (3)" width="90" x="380" y="34">
    <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="all"/>
    <parameter key="attribute" value=""/>
    <parameter key="attributes" value=""/>
    <parameter key="use_except_expression" value="false"/>
    <parameter key="value_type" value="numeric"/>
    <parameter key="use_value_type_exception" value="false"/>
    <parameter key="except_value_type" value="time"/>
    <parameter key="block_type" value="attribute_block"/>
    <parameter key="use_block_type_exception" value="false"/>
    <parameter key="except_block_type" value="value_matrix_row_start"/>
    <parameter key="numeric_condition" value="&gt; 97"/>
    <parameter key="invert_selection" value="false"/>
    <parameter key="include_special_attributes" value="false"/>
    <parameter key="mode" value="numeric"/>
    <parameter key="numeric_value" value="97.0"/>
    <parameter key="expression_value" value="&gt; 97"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="declare_missing_value" compatibility="10.1.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Declare Missing Value" width="90" x="514" y="34">
    <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="all"/>
    <parameter key="attribute" value=""/>
    <parameter key="attributes" value=""/>
    <parameter key="use_except_expression" value="false"/>
    <parameter key="value_type" value="attribute_value"/>
    <parameter key="use_value_type_exception" value="false"/>
    <parameter key="except_value_type" value="time"/>
    <parameter key="block_type" value="attribute_block"/>
    <parameter key="use_block_type_exception" value="false"/>
    <parameter key="except_block_type" value="value_matrix_row_start"/>
    <parameter key="numeric_condition" value="&gt;97"/>
    <parameter key="invert_selection" value="false"/>
    <parameter key="include_special_attributes" value="false"/>
    <parameter key="mode" value="numeric"/>
    <parameter key="numeric_value" value="98.0"/>
    <parameter key="expression_value" value="a1==99"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="declare_missing_value" compatibility="10.1.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Declare Missing Value (2)" width="90" x="648" y="34">
    <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="all"/>
    <parameter key="attribute" value=""/>
    <parameter key="attributes" value=""/>
    <parameter key="use_except_expression" value="false"/>
    <parameter key="value_type" value="attribute_value"/>
    <parameter key="use_value_type_exception" value="false"/>
    <parameter key="except_value_type" value="time"/>
    <parameter key="block_type" value="attribute_block"/>
    <parameter key="use_block_type_exception" value="false"/>
    <parameter key="except_block_type" value="value_matrix_row_start"/>
    <parameter key="numeric_condition" value="&gt;97"/>
    <parameter key="invert_selection" value="false"/>
    <parameter key="include_special_attributes" value="false"/>
    <parameter key="mode" value="numeric"/>
    <parameter key="numeric_value" value="99.0"/>
    <parameter key="expression_value" value="a1==99"/>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Create ExampleSet" from_port="output" to_op="Declare Missing Value (4)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Declare Missing Value (4)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Declare Missing Value (3)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Declare Missing Value (4)" from_port="original" to_port="result 2"/>
      <connect from_op="Declare Missing Value (3)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Declare Missing Value" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Declare Missing Value" from_port="example set output" to_op="Declare Missing Value (2)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Declare Missing Value (2)" from_port="example set output" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 3" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

The process should look like this.

[image: Process]

There are 4 examples of the `Declare Missing Values` operator. The first replaces `9999-99-99` in all attributes in all examples. The remaining 3 do the same for the numeric values 97, 98 and 99 respectively.

The output should look like this before replacements.

[image: Before]

and like this after.

[image: After]